How to add space between x axis labels and draw a vertical line after a set of IDs?
I'm trying to add space between x axis labels 10 Flows, 20 Flows, and 30 Flows and also properly draw a line after for every 1 to 8 IDs. Could someone help me with this problem?
Code:
    % restructured data file:
% - 'n' values are sorted ascending
% - added column 'z' to know which data belong to which measurement
% - added a dummy line at the end of each data set to produce an empty entry
%   for the separation of the blocks
% - put all data in one file
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
z   n   pFA pFB
10  1   6   1
10  2   7   1
10  3   8   4
10  4   9   7
10  5   10  9
10  6  0   0
10  7   9   4
10  8   12  6
20  1   6   1
20  2   7   1
20  3   8   4
20  4   9   7
20  5   10  9
20  6  0   0
20  7   9   4
20  8   12  6
30  1   6   1
30  2   7   1
30  3   8   4
30  4   9   7
30  5   10  9
30  6  0   0
30  7   9   4
30  8   12  6

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            footnotesize,
            % set the `width' of the plot to the maximum length ...
            width=\textwidth,
            % ... and use half this length for the `height'
            height=0.5\textwidth,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=100,
            %yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
            % use `data' for the positioning of the `xticks' ...
            xtick=data,
            % ... and use table data for labeling the `xticks'
            xticklabels from table={data.txt}{n},
            % add extra ticks "at the empty entries to add the vertical lines
            extra x ticks={8,16},
            % this ticks shouldn't be labeled ...
            extra x tick labels={},
            % ... but grid lines should be drawn without the tick lines
            extra x tick style={
                grid=major,
                major tick length=0pt,
            },
            xlabel={X Axis Label},
            ylabel={Y Axis Label},
            % because of the category labels, shift the `xlabel' a bit down
            xlabel style={
                yshift=-4ex,
            },
            legend pos=north west,
            legend entries={
                {\color{black}{Algorithm A}},
                {\color{red}{Algorithm B}},
            },
            area legend,
            % adjust `bar width' so it fits your needs ...
            bar width=10pt,
            % ... and with that you also have to adjust the x limits
           enlarge x limits=0.05,
            % set `clip mode' to `individual' so the category labels aren't clipped away
            clip mode=individual,
        ]

        % plot the "red" ybars
            \addplot [
                ybar,
                draw=black,
                pattern color=black,
                pattern=dots,
            ] table [
                % use just the `coordindex' as x coordinate,
                % the correct labeling is done with `xticklabels from table'
                x expr=\coordindex,
                y=pFA,
            ] {data.txt};

        % plot the "blue" ybars
            \addplot [
                ybar,
                draw=red,
                pattern color=red,
                pattern=north east lines,
            ] table [
                x expr=\coordindex,
                y=pFB,
            ] {data.txt};

        % add the category labels
            \begin{scope}[
                % because the reference point will be the lower axis line the
                % labels have to be moved a bit more down to don't overlap with
                % the `xticklabels'
                every label/.append style={
                    label distance=2ex,
                },
            ]
                \node [label=below:10 Flows]
                    at (axis cs:4,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
                \node [label=below:20 Flows]
                    at (axis cs:12,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
                \node [label=below:30 Flows]
                    at (axis cs:20,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
                % \node [label=below:40 Flows]
                %     at (axis cs:20,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
                %\node [label=below:50 Flows]
                %    at (axis cs:26,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
            \end{scope}

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output:


Could you clarify which space you want to change and which lines exactly you want to draw? Maybe show them on the output. It sounds to me that you just want extra x ticks={7.5,15.5} and to change the value in label distance=2ex.
